# In dwm how can I send a window to another tag from the command line?

Tags: x-dwm

Using the default keyboard layout in **dwm**, I can send a window to *tag 9* using `Alt+Shift+9`, for example.

**Can I do the same thing programatically?**

(I want to achieve a **toggle** feature for certain windows - showing them on one key press and hiding them on the next. I also tried working with things like `wmctrl -xR WINDOW_NAME`, but in dwm the window in question is not being pulled as it would be expected according the wmctrl man page.)

Answer (score 2):

I've just found a patch written by [ericpruitt](https://github.com/ericpruitt/mydwm#dependent) that allows to use wmctrl to send windows. The reason why it doesn't work by default is also explained:

> Because of how dwm tags work, there is not a one-to-one mapping of tag numbers and desktop numbers. For example, if a window is on tags 1 and 3 (indexed from 1) in dwm, wmctrl will report the window as being on desktop 5: 2^(1 - 1) + 2^(3 - 1).